# Add cron entry to XAMPP server

Tags: laravel, server, cron, xampp, cpanel

I am using Laravel 5.4 on Windows. In the documentation, it does not say how to add cron entries to server. I searched on YouTube, but didn't get any useful video. I need to learn how to add cron entries both to localhost and cPanel.

Comment: YouTube is not the best place to be looking for documentation, use a search engine instead. I try to discourage the idea that there is a video tutorial for everything anyway. Use documentation and Q&A sites instead.

Comment: Windows does not have Cron, it has Scheduler. If you are developing on Windows but deploying on Linux then you will need to use a different scheduling approach for each. Alternatively, use Vagrant or Docker locally, so you are effectively always running on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you can add cron only in Server Not for localhost

To add cron in cPanel follow the steps below

Step1:-
First create a cron function to which the server is going to hit,
and get the Full path like

> http://fullpath

Step2:-
Then got to cron jobs in cpanel and set the time when the cron will hit that route.

To set the time you have to follow this

> ```
>     Minutes represents the minutes of a given hour, 0-59 respectively.
>     Hours represents the hours of a given day, 0-23 respectively.
>     Days represents the days of a given month, 1-31 respectively.
>     Months represents the months of a given year, 1-12 respectively.
>     Day of the Week represents the day of the week, Sunday through Saturday, numerically, as 0-6 respectively.
> ```

[image]

Like this

Step3:-
Then Write the cron comand like

```
curl  http://fullpath
```

Like this:-

[image]

This above cron job is set for 1 sec.That means the cron will hit that route in every one sec.

Like this you can set your cron on cPanel.